# HTML display data from array in table

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I'm VERY new to HTML, and any web development for that matter, so sorry if this question is super easy. In what I have done so far, I take a few inputs from users, do some calculations on them (using a javascript function I declared in the head tag), and spit out an answer. While doing the calculations, I store values in arrays, and I would like for the user to be able to see what is in these arrays. I want to display these values in tables. But, I have no idea how to put the values of the arrays in the display for the table. I'm aware that this is how a table works:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But I would like to put my values where it says "row 1, cell 1" etc. 
From what I understand, the table tag has to be used in the body part of the HTML code (please tell me if I'm wrong!) so I don't know how to do this. I can't just create the table while calculating my values in my function, right? How can I access the arrays that I created and stored values in in my function? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please give us a example from the array you want to display as a HTML table.

Comment: Is what you want, an initial blank table, and then you dynamically add rows with data to it?

Comment: nope, the table will be 4 columns and 360 rows, so I understand that I can have a for loop running through the array, but how I access it is the question I guess?

Comment: give your cells ids, and then access them with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create tables, actually, even with functions, but to simplify, lets use your table already there.

WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KEjpe/

JS:

```
var myjsonobject = { 
                    0: { 0: "row 1 cell 1", 1 : "row 1 cell 2"},
                    1: { 0: "row 2 cell 1", 1 : "row 2 cell 2"} 
                   }

var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

var trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(i=0;i<trs.length;i++)
{
   var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

   for(j=0;j<tds.length;j++)
   {
      tds[j].innerHTML = myjsonobject[i][j]
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so as I'm calculating my values, I need to store them in this 2-d JSON object, and then do what you've given above?

Comment: ok i did it in jsfiddle to iron out any minor errors. I have fully working example now with jsfiddle it populates the table successfully with JSON stored values. I hope this helps you. Pure JS, no jQuery dependency!

Comment: so i just need to create the JSON object with the values I calculate, wow! thank you so much!

Comment: that's right you put it in your head <script> tag or you put it in an external js file loaded by <script src> tag, and the html just as is in the body tag. It will work and should output like in my jsfiddle demo

Comment: well, sorry I'm so new to this stuff and since you've been so helpful: how do I create the JSON object with the values in my arrays?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22292/discussion-between-gagan-gupta-and-sajawikio)

Answer (score 1):

First you need a function to append tr and td to your table.

```
function addContentTo(table, myArr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for (var col in myArr) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innetHTML = col;
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    frag.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(frag);
}
```

Now you can rum your lines array to populate your table:

```
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
for(var line in myArray) {
    addContentTo(table, line);
}
```

I'm suposing that your array is something like this:

```
myArray = [
    ['row 1, cell 1', 'row 1, cell 2'],
    ['row 2, cell 1', 'row 2, cell 2']
];
```

Then your table will be constructed dynamic, but in my code case your table must have id 'mytable':

```
<table id="mytable"></table>
```

That's all folks.